# Updating text on JFrame depending on ActionListener

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, actionlistener

This is a result of ActionListener. Depending on what he chooses in the Combo Box it returns a price. I just want it as a simple $39.99. Nothing more.

I have the

```
packageIndex = packageChoice.getSelectedIndex();
```

All the prices are in an array:

```
String[] prices = {"49.99, 39.99, 34.99, 99.99"}
```

Now I need to know how to pull the price out and display it and be able to work with the data later on. But I don't know how to pull a piece of the array out and set it to another variable.

Comment: All fixed. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the array like:

```
String[] prices = {"49.99", "39.99", "34.99", "99.99"}
```

then you can get individual prices using:

```
String price = prices[packageIndex];
```

Comment: I declared price as a double and set the prices array to doubles. I need to work the data later.